# Instantly starting the given route when opening Google Maps from my Flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart, geolocation, location

I have a kind of delivery app made with Flutter, where the driver selects a customer in a list and presses the according button to start navigation to that customer, e.g. open the navigation app (on Android devices I open Google Maps). For that, I'm currently using the [map_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/map_launcher) package. Here is the code:

```
 await MapLauncher.showDirections(
        mapType: Platform.isIOS || Platform.isMacOS ? MapType.apple : MapType.google,
        // origin: Coords(currentPosition.latitude, currentPosition.longitude),
        destination: Coords(station.address.lat!, station.address.lng!),
      )
```

Now our customer wants it so that navigation starts immediatly, meaning the calculated route is **already selected and started**. Right now it only shows the preview for the route, and the user has to press start manually. I have tried different methods and packages, but none seem to provide the functionality that I'm looking for. I know that it is possible because I have an (android native) app that does exactly that.

Is there a way to achieve aforementioned feature, with [map_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/map_launcher) or any other package that opens up a map/navigation app? Or do I have to write native code for that?